# Extract names from File using Ruby and Grep

Tags: ruby, grep

I have a file with the following data:

```
other data
user1=name1
user2=name2
user3=name3
other data
```

to extract the names I do the following

```
names = File.open('resource.cfg', 'r') do |f|
  f.grep(/[a-z][a-z][0-9]/)
end
```

which returns the following array

```
user1=name1
user2=name2
user3=name3
```

but I really want only the name part

```
name1
name2
name3
```

Right now I'm doing this after the file step:

```
names = names.map do |name|
  name[7..9]
end
```

is there a better way to do? with the file step

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it like this, using [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regex:

**Code**

```
File.read(FNAME).scan(/(?<==)[A-Za-z]+\d+$/)
```

**Explanation**

Let's start by constructing a file:

```
FNAME = "my_file"

lines =<<_
other data
user1=name1
user2=name2
user3=name3
other data
_

File.write(FNAME,lines)
```

We can confirm the file contents:

```
puts File.read(FNAME)
other data
user1=name1
user2=name2
user3=name3
other data
```

Now run the code::

```
File.read(FNAME).scan(/(?<==)[A-Za-z]+\d+$/)
  #=> ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
```

A word about the regex I used.

```
(?<=...)
```

is called a "positive lookbehind".  Whatever is inserted in place of the dots must immediately precede the match, but is not part of the match (and for that reason is sometimes referred to as as "zero-length" group).  We want the match to follow an equals sign, so the "positive lookbehind" is as follows:

```
(?<==)
```

This is followed by one or more letters, then one or more digits, then an end-of-line, which comprise the pattern to be matched.  You could of course change this if you have different requirements, such as names being lowercase or beginning with a capital letter, a specified number of digits, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for this. I never had used lookbehinds in regexs before and now they make so much more sense.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you found it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Is your code working as you have posted it?

```
names = File.open('resource.cfg', 'r') { |f| f.grep(/[a-z][a-z][0-9]/) }
names = names.map { |name| name[7..9] }
=> ["ame", "ame", "ame"]
```

You could make it into a neat little one-liner by writing it as such:

```
names = File.readlines('resource.cfg').grep(/=(\w*)/) { |x| x.split('=')[1].chomp }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in a single step:

```
names = File.open('resource.cfg', 'r') do |f|
    f.grep(/[a-z][a-z][0-9]/).map {|x| x.split('=')[1]}
end
```

Comment: `grep` can take a block too: `f.grep(/=(\w*)/) { |x| x.split('=')[1].chomp }`